# Checking values in two different files in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to verify column values in two separate files. The file paths for the two files are in two separate cells in the same sheet. I got it to work for one file but I need to verify column values in two separate sheets. This is what I have tried so far.

However, I am getting the error message. "Compile error:vInvalid Next control variable reference" And it highlights `Next x`. Why?

```
Sub ButtonSearch_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Name of columns to be found
JiraColumns = Array("CRM#", "status", "Key", "Resolution", "Assignee", "Customer Name", "Company")
SparksColumns = Array("QCCR", "Hpsw Status")

' Define boundaries
For x = LBound(JiraColumns) To UBound(JiraColumns)
    For y = LBound(SparksColumns) To UBound(SparksColumns)

        ' Search for column names on general_report Sheet
        With oWB.Sheets("general_report")
            Set foundRange = .Cells.Find(What:=JiraColumns(x), After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        End With

        If foundRange Is Nothing Then
            ' Missing Column
            intRow = 1
            MsgBox "Jira is missing Column: " & (JiraColumns(x))
            oWB.Close False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Count = Count + 1
        End If

    Next x

    ' *** *** Sparks verification *** ***  SECOND FILE, SECOND FILE, SECOND FILE *** *** ***

    With sWB.Sheets("Sample-Sparks")
        Set foundR = .Cells.Find(What:=SparksColumns(y), After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                 LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

    If foundR Is Nothing Then
        ' Missing Column
        intRow = 1
        MsgBox "Sparks is missing Column: " & (SparksColumns(y))
        sWB.Close False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        CountS = CountS + 1
    End If

Next y

If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then foundRange.Activate
If Not foundR Is Nothing Then foundR.Active

' close the source workbook without saving any changes
oWB.Close False

' free memory
Set wbFind = Nothing

' Show activity on screen
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Proper code indentation will go a long way toward making this type of mistake obvious... See how I indented your code in your question. It is then obvious that you swapped `Next x` and `Next y`.

Comment: Please don't change your question after it has been answered... If you have a new problem, ask a new question. I have rolled back your changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up your next-loops. Your y loop should be nested inside you x loop. I.e.

```
For x = LBound(JiraColumns) To UBound(JiraColumns)
    For y = LBound(SparksColumns) To UBound(SparksColumns)
    '...code...
    Next y
'...code...
Next x
```

---

**The other problem** regarding the error in the line `SFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F17").Value` occurs because you, in the line before that, opens the file on the `JFile`path. Because the `JFile` is now you `ActiveWorkook` and that workbook doesn't contain a sheet named `Sheet1` you receive the error message.

You need to be careful on which workbook is the active workbook when working with multiple workbooks. You could declare you workbooks like (in this case the `ActiveWorkbook`):

```
Dim ActWB As Workbook
Set ActWB = ActiveWorkbook
```

And then get the `sFile` value like:

```
sfile = ActWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F17").Value
```

Likewise cells in the `JFile` can be referenced like (for example): `oWB.sheets("Test").range("A1").value`

Comment: Ok, I tried it and now I have the error message "Run-time error '9'
Subscript out of range" This error message seems to be very common

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing exactly what line the error occurs in.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I have edited my code. Thank you for your help Sr.

Comment: It looks like there is no sheet named `Sheet1`

Comment: Well, if the first JFile can find it why not the SFile? I think both of them are getting values from the same sheet just different cell right? Thank you Sr.

Comment: I just saw what the problem is. I have tried to explain by updating my answer.